# Как передать аргументы командной строки дочерней команде?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Есть файлы(картинки) которые нужно обработать (урезать в размере) программой Image Magick в модуле `subprocess` и положить в папку Result. Как правильно передать аргументы?

```
path = r"./Source" 
programm_process = subprocess.Popen(["convert", os.path.join(path, "face-04.jpg"),
                                     "-resize 200", os.makedirs("Result")])
```

В итоге должна получиться такая команда:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 200 output.jpg
```

Comment: os.makedirs не возвращает путь/пути - вместо него там None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну создайте перед работой дерево каталогов и используйте относительные пути к директориям. Как создавать вы уже знаете: `os.makedirs("...")`

```
source = r"./Source"
dest =  r"./Dest"
programm_process = subprocess.Popen(["convert", os.path.join(source, "face-04.jpg"), 
                                    "-resize", 200, os.path.join(dest, "output.jpg")])
```

И еще на заметку: каждый параметр, будь то ключ или значение должен быть отдельным элементом списка, в вашем примере: `..., "-resize 200" ,...` работать не будет, нужно разбивать: `..., "-resize", 200, ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
with subprocess.Popen(['ping', '127.0.0.1', '-t']) as pid:
    pid.communicate()
```

Comment: Не используйте communicate() если ввод/вывод дочернего процесса не перенаправлен.  Можно просто записать: `subprocess.run(['ping', '8.8.8.8'])`

Answer (score 0):

Каждый аргумент следует как отдельный элемент списка передать. К примеру, чтобы запустить команду:

```
$ convert input.jpg -resize 20x10 output.jpg
```

Используя subprocess модуль:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call("convert input.jpg -resize 20x10 output.jpg".split())
```